# Unable to Delete a Corrupted Directory After Filebrowser Crash

Tags: ubuntu, debian, armbian

I am a bit new to this, so apologies if I miss something.

I was using [filebrowser](https://filebrowser.org/) to upload a few big files earlier today and it crashed. Everything works, however I am unable to delete a directory, it may be corrupted.

When I run the rm command this is the output

```
rm -dfv /media/files/ssd/mmove/xyz
```

`rm: cannot remove '/media/files/ssd/mmove/xyz ': Directory not empty`

I am unsure of the next steps, hope you could help.

I am able to unmount the drive using the umount command but when I try to run fsck this is the output.

```
fsck -t ntfs -f /dev/nvme0n1
```

`fsck from util-linux 2.37.2`

I think the command does not run or it just exists instantly.